# How to stop a ongoing import in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have setup a jdbc river wiht oneshot strategy and successfuly imported my DB data.

But when I restart the server it's begin to reindex all data again.

How can I stop this process ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When river is done, you can just delete it from the _river index using this command:

```
curl -XDELETE localhost:9200/_river/you_river_name
```

Answer (score 0):

You can close the river and then re-open at a later point of time:

```
POST _river/_close
```

To open:

```
POST _river/_open
```

Note: I have executed these from sense where my cluster ip is : localhost:9200

**Update**

DELETE  _river will do.